Build and Deploy Job failing due to invaid Node version on Azure
I have an Angular App which is building fine on my local with Latest Angular and Node versions.. However, when i deploy it to Azure Static Web app, the build is failing and giving the below error.
Node.js version v16.20.2 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of v18.19.
I have included the engine tag in package.json as below.. but its not helping.. Can someone please help here
"engines": {
    "node": ">=18.0.0"
  },


Can you share your github repo if possible?

Provide your .yml file

As @Sirra Sneha mentions, in order to help please provide details about how the Angular app is being deployed to Azure Static Web Apps. This may include a sample from related GitHub Actions workflow YAML files in the .github/workflows directory

I created a sample angular application and have successfully deployed the app to Azure static web app via GitHub actions.
I got the same error while deploying the app to Azure Static Web App.


Thanks to @Richard Huf for the clear steps, I referred to this doc and added the .nvmrc file to the root diectory of the project.

Add the Node.js version you are using to this file:
v20.14.0

In .yml file I've Added node-version: '20.x' under actions/setup-node@v2.

This will ensure that Node.js version 20.x is used for the build process.


Complete yaml file:
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          lfs: false
      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '20.x' 
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Build Angular app
        run: npm run build -- --configuration=production
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_AMBITIOUS_STONE_0BC3E2B0F }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          action: "upload"
          app_location: "/" 
          output_location: "dist/angulartest18/browser" 
          
  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_AMBITIOUS_STONE_0BC3E2B0F }}
          action: "close"

Successfully deployed the app to Azure Static Web App via GitHub actions.



@Sam K Is your issue resolved?
